# control scanf() duration for taking any input

Tags: c, scanf

i thought about controlling scanf for taking any input in c.my concept is about waiting for 10 seconds(or any other time) to take any input.after 10 seconds it will exit and will no more receive any input.

```
 int main(){
 int a,b,c,d;
 scanf("%d",&a);
 printf("10 seconds are over no more input");
 }
```

here i want to control the time to take its input.after 10 seconds the input panel will no longer remain and the text "10 seconds are over no more input" will be printed.

Comment: what operatiing system are you on?

Comment: You miss `#include <stdio.h>`; if on Linux you might consider [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html); edit your question to improve it

Comment: i am on win 7 -64 bit

Comment: Not possible with Standard C. On Unix you could use select() or poll() but I don't know the equivalents for Win7.

Comment: hpwever iused clock() to calculate the time period of scanf to take input.if the time interval between start and end of scanf is greater than 10 sec then the program will exit.buyt its not the exact solution i guess.

Comment: If you want to use the clock is will require input due _kbhit not scanf. Or CreateProcess something like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int num = 0;
    DWORD waitCode;
    printf("input number : ");
    //wait console input 10,000 Millisecond
    waitCode = WaitForSingleObject(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE) , 10*1000);
    switch(waitCode){
    case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
        fprintf(stderr, "\n10 seconds are over no more input\n");
        return -1;
    case WAIT_OBJECT_0://normal status
        scanf("%d", &num);//input from stdin buffer
        if(num)//not zero
            printf("input number is %d\n", num);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

**ADD**
Thread version

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void ThreadProc(void *);

int main(void){
    int num = 0;
    DWORD waitCode;
    DWORD ThreadID = 0;
    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0,
                        (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)ThreadProc,
                        (LPVOID)&num, 0, &ThreadID);
    if(!hThread){
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create a thread\n");
        return -1;
    }

    waitCode = WaitForSingleObject(hThread, 10*1000);   
    switch(waitCode){
    case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
        fprintf(stderr, "\n10 seconds are over no more input\n");
        break;
    case WAIT_OBJECT_0://normal status
        if(num)//not zero
            printf("input number is %d\n", num);
    }
    CloseHandle(hThread);

    return 0;
}

void ThreadProc(void *n){
    int *num = n;
    printf("input number : ");
    scanf("%d", num);
    ExitThread(0);
}
```

Comment: times out when there is no input for more than 10 seconds is not a `scanf` end of time .